# How to make Delayed_Job notify Airbrake when an ActionMailer runs into an error?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, actionmailer, delayed-job

The DelayedJob docs mention hooks, including an error hook, but only in the context of custom Job subclasses.

[This similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11766368/error-reporting-when-sending-emails-with-delayed-job) (with no answers) says adding the same hook to the mailer class did not work.

What's the trick?

**Update:**

In general, I'd like to see how to add hooks to jobs that are triggered using the `object.delay.action()` syntax, where I don't see an obvious link to a `____Job` class.

Comment: Updated and simpler answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11766368/error-reporting-when-sending-emails-with-delayed-job/17029430#17029430

Answer (score 20, accepted):

I was just searching for a solution to this problem too, and I found [this gist](https://gist.github.com/2223758).

I don't know where it comes from (found it on Google), but well, it seems to do the job pretty well, is quite simple, and seems to follow a DelayedJob's plugin system I was not even aware of...

Here is a lightly improved one using parts of previous monkey-patch code:

```
# https://gist.github.com/2223758
# modified

module Delayed
  module Plugins
    class Airbrake < Plugin
      module Notify
        def error(job, error)
          ::Airbrake.notify_or_ignore(
            :error_class   => error.class.name,
            :error_message => "#{error.class.name}: #{error.message}",
            :parameters    => {
              :failed_job => job.inspect,
            }
          )
          super if defined?(super)
        end
      end

      callbacks do |lifecycle|
        lifecycle.before(:invoke_job) do |job|
          payload = job.payload_object
          payload = payload.object if payload.is_a? Delayed::PerformableMethod
          payload.extend Notify
        end
      end
    end
  end
end

Delayed::Worker.plugins << Delayed::Plugins::Airbrake
```

It will add the error's message and payload so that it's available in Airbrake.

Comment: I was not aware of this plugin system, either. I'll take a look. If this works in my system, I'll be switching the accepted answer to yours soon.

Comment: I really like this approach.  I couldn't find a version released as a gem, so in thanks for sharing this, I packaged it as a gem for others to easily use.  If you'd like write access, etc, please let me know!  https://github.com/benjaminoakes/delayed-plugins-airbrake

Comment: This is the best answer because it works on *all* jobs, it's *not* a monkeypatch, and you don't have to remember to add a hook when you add a new usage of `delay`.  Also, I would use @benjamin-oakes gem except that I'm using party_foul instead of airbrake.

Answer (score 2):

There's a DJ-honeybadger gem. The gem is of course actively maintained which makes it much better than using a monkey patch. Granted, when the monkey patch came out, there was no gem to do this.

https://github.com/honeybadger-io/delayed_job_honeybadger

Comment: Thanks, The question was for Airbrake, but this is a similar, good answer. (There's also an Airbrake gem, now). https://github.com/benjaminoakes/delayed-plugins-airbrake

Comment: You're right @JordanFeldstein the question was for Airbrake. Funnily I used the same hack for honeybadger and it worked pretty well. I guess Airbrake and Honeybadger have APIs that respond to the same calls (very good thing)

Comment: This plugin is now deprecated for the latest version of Honeybadger.

Answer (score 1):

The best method would be to use Global Hooks. Someone [proposed](https://github.com/collectiveidea/delayed_job/wiki/Global-Hooks-Proposal) this in 2011, but doesn't look like they've been implemented yet.

In the mean time, this works to monkey patch things:

```
# Patch delayed job to report runtime errors to Airbrake
module Delayed
  class Worker

    protected

    def handle_failed_job_with_airbrake(job, error)
      ::Airbrake.notify(
        :error_class   => error.class.name,
        :error_message => "#{error.class.name}: #{error.message}",
        :parameters    => {
          :failed_job => job.inspect,
        }
      )

      handle_failed_job_without_airbrake(job, error)
    end

    alias_method_chain :handle_failed_job, :airbrake

  end
end
```

Comment: Because of the way Airbrake shows parameters, I'd recommend not sending `job.inspect` but instead pass a hash. First parse the contents of the failed job: `failed_job = YAML.load(job.handler)`. Then parse it's instance parameters into a hash, which you can pass to the `:parameters` for airbrake: `failed_job.instance_variables.inject({}) { |hsh,v| hsh[v.to_s.gsub(/[^\w]/, '')] = failed_job.instance_variable_get(v); hsh }`

Comment: You might also want to include the class name of the job in the `:parameters` too: `:class => failed_job.class.name`

Answer (score 1):

Probably the simplest way to get delayed_job to send through an alert to Airbrake when the job fails is to monkey-patch delayed_job. This allows you to hook into delayed_job's internals, and modify it slightly to alert Airbrake when something goes wrong.

Unfortunately, exactly how to do this will depend on which version of delayed_job you are using, and which version of Airbrake you are using; it will also depend, perhaps, on exactly where within the delayed_job processing you want to hook into the system.

However, probably the simplest example I have seen for how to do what you want is to monkey-patch the handle_failed_job method, as seen [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1276164/how-do-i-integrate-hoptoad-with-delayedjob-and-daemonspawn/7170605#7170605). Note though that this example uses the old Hoptoad system for the alerting, so if you're using a modern Airbrake gem, you'll need to change the code that does the actual notifying to be as described [here](https://github.com/airbrake/airbrake/wiki/Sending-notices-to-Airbrake-manually-from-controllers).

Comment: THanks for reminding me. I eventually came across the same monkey patch solution. Code snipped above.